# How do I make a shared queue?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

From what I understood, every partition can have only 1 consumer (per consumer group), and wanting to make a queue I must use only 1 consumer group as multiple ones would get the same messages

Problem: I have 2 consumers, Every event processed by the consumer/s may take from 1 minute to 30 minutes, I make 2 partitions to distribute events between the 2 consumers.
First partition gets 2 events that need 30 minutes each to process, second partition gets 1 event that needs just 1 minute to process. Is there no way to make a shared queue? Like, as soon as a worker/consumer is free, it pulls another event where its needed (multiple consumers for the same partition, but not reading the same events twice)?

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there no way to make a shared queue?"

A single partition can only be consumed by one consumer within the Consumer Group. This concept cannot be changed.

You could increase the number of partitions to a higher number hoping that the events that take a lot of time to be processed are evenly distributed accross partitions in the long run. Or, even better, if you have the knowledge in advance about the processing time and you have control over the producer you could steer the partitioning of the events manually to achieve the evenly distribution.

If you do not have control over the producer you could have a dedicated consumer that just does the distribution into a second topic and then let the processing job consume from the second topic.